# How to put multiple control events for forControlEvents?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see that it says forControlEvents (plural) meaning I can put more than one!

However, I'm not sure what's the correct syntax.

Instead, I've just placed two lines of code that speak to the same selector.

```
[myLoginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonScaleRelease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myLoginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonScaleRelease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

Can anyone please explain me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you are using Objective-C still rather than swift.  It accepts a bitmask, so try

```
[myLoginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonScaleRelease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

Comment: I suggest learning Swift, as Objective-C use seems to be reducing quite a lot.

Comment: @Lucky This has got nothing do with the Objective-C; you don't understand bitmasks and that won't change if you move to Swift.

Comment: progressSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderTouchEvents), for: UIControlEvents .valueChanged | UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)   I am gettin errors are :   '|' is not a postfix unary operator,Cannot convert value of type 'UIControlEvents' to expected argument type 'UInt8',         
Replace 'UIControlEvents .valueChanged' with 'UInt8(UIControlEvents .valueChanged.rawValue)'

Answer (score 0):

Lucky it is possible to put multiple control events on same action method.If you write different action(addTarget) for button,it takes different action(what you write addTarget action method in selector). So touch up inside the button and touch up outside the button action method here work. So the below two events definitely  work.

```
[myLoginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonScaleRelease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myLoginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonScaleRelease) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```